# Deleted parition when creating W10 boot

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I made a mistake, and created a partition on a 2TB external hard drive to create a boot of W10, but didn't take my information out of the other partition and the bootable deleted all of my photos and private information. I need to recover all of my files (over 80gb) and I don't seem to find a way on how to do it. Recovery software is really expensive and I really don't know where else to ask.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva/download) by Piriform (of CCLeaner fame) is a pretty competent tool. Provided you've not written any data to the drive since you formatted it, it might be able to retrieve some of your data with the Deep Scan option.

Best of luck.

Comment: The partition where my info was is unallocated, does that mean that everything is erased? Maybe if I create a volume everything will be there?

Comment: Unallocated in the Windows Disk Manager can just mean that it doesn't recognize the partition type or file system. DO NO WRITE DATA to that drive. Creating a volume, renaming it, formatting, chkdsk, anything. You will destroy your data by writing to that volume, if it is still there.

Comment: Then how can I get back the data from an unallocated partition?